# Java 17 Spring Boot spring-boot-maven-plugin addResources make .properties file unavailable to the application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, properties-file

I'm currently working on a spring-boot project.

We use thymeleaf templates for our admin panel. In order to enable hot-reload we've used the spring-boot-maven plugin like so:

```
plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${springboot.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <addResources>true</addResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The addResources property adds all resources to the classpath directly, enabling us to hot reload any thymeleaf template after saving the file. Everything works well when deploying into an Application server or running the app with InteliJ spring boot run configuration. However, attempting to run the application from the command line like so:

```
mvn clean package spring-boot:run -P dev
```

results in the application not being able to access the .properties files.

Obviously swapping the addResources property to false fixes the issue, with the cost of no longer being able to hot-reload the files. Is there a way to achieve this hot-reload functionality while being able to access the .property files?

Answer (score 0):

When using **`<addResources>true</addResources>`** the filtering of resources at build time will not work.

Sample with **`<addResources>true</addResources>`** :
[image]

Sample with **`<addResources>false</addResources>`** :
[image]

You can put your spring version and the properties files please.

Comment: Well, yes, obviously setting  the addResources property to true deletes the resource files, as per documentation "Add maven resources to the classpath directly, this allows live in-place editing of
resources. Duplicate resources are removed from {@code target/classes} to prevent
them from appearing twice if {@code ClassLoader.getResources()} is called."

What I would want is to be able to access the properties values from my app when running it from console.

Comment: @ZdrzalikPrzemyslaw you can put your spring version and when your code coud not acces to *.propeties